# Initialization of collection throwing error in Class

Tags: c#, list, class, exception, collections

I'm trying access a public collection(list) to display an indexed object from that collection in some text boxes.

```
public partial class UpdateStudentScores : Form 
{
    int index;
    private StudentList students = new StudentList();

    public UpdateStudentScores(int target)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        index = target;
    }

    private void UpdateStudentScores_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtName.Text = students[index].WholeName;
    }

}
```

I run the program and try to load the data but I get an exception in my StudentList.cs

```
    public Student this [int i]
    {
        get 
        {
            return students[i];
        }
        set
        {
            students[i] = value;
            Changed(this);
        }
    }
```

The exception indicates that my index is out of range. My students[] has no objects in it. When I remove this:

private StudentList students = new StudentList();

from my UpdateStudentScores.cs, I no longer have that exception. How is the initialization my that collection interfering with the population of my StudentList class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is loading/initializing but there is nothing at index zero in your list.  No where in the code are you loading items into the collection.

Your variable `index` is a value type and defaults with zero.

```
txtName.Text = students[index].WholeName;
```

Comment: Bingo! added students.Fill(); and it worked. Someday I'll know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless an array, a `List<T>` is empty when it has been created (`list.Count == 0`). You must add items before you can access them through the index.

```
public Student this [int i]
{
    get 
    {
        return students[i];
    }
    set
    {
        if (i < students.Count) {
            students[i] = value;
            Changed(this);
        } else if (i == students.Count) {
            students.Add(value);
            Changed(this);
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(
                "Student at this index is not accessible.");
        }
    }
}
```